# How can I ensure my backup user has access to all files created by arbitrary processes with arbitrary UMASK, users, groups, and permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, backup, container

Rather than run as `root`, my Duplicati container runs its own UID/GID [using the Linuxserver.io image]. This is great from a file creation and process running perspective to minimise confusion and unnecessary privilege. However, this has an unintended side effect on accessing source files for backup locally on the same filesystem/OS; it now does not have access to all files by default. This is also great except...

...files are not created equally. They are created from processes (also running in containers from both custom Dockerfile and public registries) that create files and directories through many arbitrary, distinct file (permission) configurations.

In a perfect world the Duplicati UID would simply be in all groups used by all all the source file creation processes. But some processes, containers, etc, use strange or uncontrollable UMASK, default file creation modes, or even some files are intentionally not readably permissioned beyond the user owner.

**So on to my question:** how can I continue to run Duplicati within the container as its own distinct user, but allow it to act as `root` in the (local) filesystem to allow it to backup all files?

Obviously there's a route where I can repermission or `chown` the files before each run, but this potentially breaks certain applications that only run when certain permissions are present, or it breaks other security best practice.

---

*EDIT 2022-08-09 17:58 (UTC+1):* Thanks to @telcoM I've created a `custom-cont-init.d` script (as provided by the Linuxserver.io container I'm working with):

```
apt update && apt install -y libcap2-bin && apt clean
setcap cap_dac_override=+ep /usr/bin/mono-sgen
```

I can now see the appropriate `cap_dac_override` capability lit up on the process using `getpcaps`:

```
root@dc42a0e3e0d7:/# ps auxnww
    USER     PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
       0       1  0.0  0.0    200    28 ?        Ss   Aug08   0:00 /package/admin/s6/command/s6-svscan -d4 -- /run/service
       0      16  0.0  0.0    204    16 ?        S    Aug08   0:00 s6-supervise s6-linux-init-shutdownd
       0      18  0.0  0.0    196     4 ?        Ss   Aug08   0:00 /package/admin/s6-linux-init/command/s6-linux-init-shutdownd -c /run/s6/basedir -g 3000 -C -B
       0      27  0.0  0.0    204    20 ?        S    Aug08   0:00 s6-supervise s6rc-oneshot-runner
       0      28  0.0  0.0    204    20 ?        S    Aug08   0:00 s6-supervise s6rc-fdholder
       0      35  0.0  0.0    180     4 ?        Ss   Aug08   0:00 /package/admin/s6/command/s6-ipcserverd -1 -- /package/admin/s6/command/s6-ipcserver-access -v0 -E -l0 -i data/rules -- /package/admin/s6/command/s6-sudod -t 30000 -- /package/admin/s6-rc/command/s6-rc-oneshot-run -l ../.. --
       0     471  0.0  0.0    204    20 ?        S    Aug08   0:00 s6-supervise duplicati
   20031     473  0.0  0.1 146324 14756 ?        Ssl  Aug08   0:00 mono Duplicati.Server.exe --webservice-interface=any --server-datafolder=/config --webservice-allowed-hostnames=*
   20031     481 17.6  2.1 2273276 175044 ?      Sl   Aug08 249:35 /usr/bin/mono-sgen /app/duplicati/Duplicati.Server.exe --webservice-interface=any --server-datafolder=/config --webservice-allowed-hostnames=*
       0     501  0.0  0.0   6872   492 pts/0    Ss+  Aug08   0:00 /bin/bash
       0    1278  0.0  0.0   7040  3556 pts/1    Ss   17:33   0:00 /bin/bash
       0    1315  0.0  0.0   8468  2796 pts/1    R+   17:52   0:00 ps auxnww
root@dc42a0e3e0d7:/# cat /config/custom-cont-init.d/
21-extra-group-id       31-setcap-dac-override
root@dc42a0e3e0d7:/# cat /config/custom-cont-init.d/31-setcap-dac-override
apt update && apt install -y libcap2-bin && apt clean
setcap cap_dac_override=+ep /usr/bin/mono-sgen
root@dc42a0e3e0d7:/# getpcaps 471
471: = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap+ep
root@dc42a0e3e0d7:/# getpcaps 473
473: = cap_dac_override+ep
root@dc42a0e3e0d7:/# getpcaps 481
481: = cap_dac_override+ep
```

And whilst my first smaller backup test worked without any of the previous filesystem permission errors, I'm still getting them for the much larger/slower backup. Is there anything else I'm missing to get this to work as I'd hope?

---

EDIT 2022-08-30 13:09 (UTC+1): The accepted answer likely works, just not for me. I'm running this container on a Docker Swarm: `The cap_add and cap_drop options are ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode` which comes from the [Docker Compose reference docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#cap_add-cap_drop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be best solved by using Linux capabilities (see `man 7 capabilities`).

For backup jobs, `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` might suffice to allow it to read (and thus backup) everything that exists in any part of the filesystem namespace it can see. For restore jobs, you might need `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` to be able to write anywhere, plus `CAP_CHOWN`, `CAP_FOWNER` and `CAP_FSETID` to be able to restore any ownerships, permissions and ACLs.

Docker has facilities that allow you to configure your containers with capabilities: things like this is what those facilities are for.

Comment: I've used capabilities for hardware/network device interactions, but wasn't aware there were more of them for filesystem access! I'll take a look at that `man` page and the examples you provided! Thanks! Will come back and mark as answer once I've tried it out.

Comment: Running the first backup now... will know the results in 5-6 hours...

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked so far. I wonder if the way that the container switches over to the non-root user is meaning the capabilities are not being applied to the spawned process. Is there a way I can check what capabilities exist on a running process?

Comment: That might indeed be the reason. If the `capsh` command is available (or can be made available) within the container, that would be a capabilities-aware way to switch users, e.g. `capsh --keep=1 --user=backup-user -- command-to-execute`. `getpcaps PID` will list the capabilities on a process specified by PID.

Comment: I've updated my question with more findings. I'm close, but uncertain whether I've gone about things the wrong way. For your suggestion, I'd need to bind mount override [the existing services.d init script](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-duplicati/blob/master/root/etc/services.d/duplicati/run) (or build my own forked image) for the container to be able to use capsh - would you say that your approach would be better than mine of applying the capability to the executable?

Comment: Ah... I've just found why it doesn't work for me... I'm running these on a Docker Swarm:  `The cap_add and cap_drop options are ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode` from the [Docker Compose reference docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#cap_add-cap_drop).

Comment: but since this does answer the question, I've marked it as answer.

Comment: Applying the capability to the executable is also a valid way to solve the problem, although it means anyone who can run the executable will also have access to the capability... although in a container, this is not likely to be a significant issue.